# Milk seems to make the dog gentler and calmer -- why?

Tags: dogs, feeding

Whenever the dogs hear me steam milk at my coffee machine, they come running because they know I'll give them a fingerful of milk foam from the inside of the empty milk container. This is a treat they love and since it's foam, they don't know they're hardly getting any milk at all.

The interesting part is how they seem to relax as soon as they start to lick -- the licks are gentler and slower than when they lick or eat anything else.

This makes me wonder if there is some instinctual reason for this -- maybe they are slowing down because they're trying not to be rough as if they're nursing? I read something about casein having a calming influence on puppies who nurse, but I don't know if this is the same thing.

Comment: Could it be because they're licking it off your finger as opposed to the floor or a food dish? Dogs generally understand to be gentle when eating something on/from a human.

Comment: Could they be related to the smell/taste of their mothers milk? The gentleness might come from when they were suckling.

Comment: My guess would be that the warmth makes them slow down a bit.

Comment: As @Eager said the tryptophan possibly  contributes

Comment: It's not too warm by the time they get it, but it's not cold for sure. There is a noticeable difference in how they lick it compared to other things like, say, sauce or something yummy from dinner.